# Bridging ERC-20 Tokens to SPL Tokens with Tax Features Using Wormhole or Similar Platforms

Tags: erc-20, bridge

I'm exploring the possibility of bridging ERC-20 tokens to a similar contract on the Solana blockchain using Wormhole or a comparable platform. My primary concern is the retention of specific token properties, like buy and sell taxes, post-bridging.

From my understanding, Wormhole facilitates the bridging process by creating a wrapped version of the original ERC-20 token on Solana. However, this seems to lead to a loss of certain token functionalities, particularly those related to transaction taxes. The wrapped tokens do not appear to maintain these features.

My question is: Is there a method to create an SPL token using the Token 2022 Program on Solana that supports transaction taxes? Furthermore, can this SPL token be linked to the original ERC-20 token using the Wormhole contract, ensuring that the tax functionalities are preserved in the bridging process?

I'm relatively new to blockchain technology, and the concept of token bridging, especially across different blockchains like Ethereum and Solana, is quite complex to me. Any guidance, insights, or resources on this topic would be greatly appreciated.